# Man-in-the-Middle Mobile (e.g. Android) Application Tool

Tags: android, man-in-the-middle, ios, burp-suite, mobile-app

I'm trying to MITM an Android application but I cannot get it to work properly. Usually, I'm using Burp for those kind of attacks, which allows me to intercept and decrypt HTTPS traffic. (Assuming the certificate is installed on the Android device.)

However, it seems the application I'm currently testing is using a non-HTTP(S) protocol, but still TCP at port 443. I've googled my issue and discovered the following Burp plugin:
https://github.com/summitt/Burp-Non-HTTP-Extension

Sadly, this plugin does not work properly for me and other's seem to have similar issues. I've also discovered mitmproxy but this just like burp only works on HTTP(S) traffic.

Does someone have any idea on how to perform a MITM on this application and which tool I should be using?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by using a Kali VM and forwarding the HTTP (80) and HTTPS (443) ports to another machine that was running Burp like so:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wlan0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination <IP>:<PORT>
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wlan0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination <IP>:<PORT>
```

While I'm still unable to see any traffic in Burp the certificate pinning check of the application fails now, which proves that it is running through Burp.